# Hotkey to format Excel fields as DateTime?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way I can create a hotkey to format a field from text to datetime? I can use Ctrl+Shift+# (21-Oct-13) to format to Date and Ctrl+Shift+@ (4:19 PM) to format as time. I'd like to see the date *and* the time. I know I can go into Format Cells... but I'd like a quicker way of doing this.

Is there an easy way to do this or to create a macro to accomplish this?

Excel 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recorded the following macro in Excel 2007 but should translate to 2010:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]m/d/yy h:mm AM/PM;@"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd have to load that Macro for each excel document?

Comment: You could, yes.  There is another alternative I have not personally used before, but seems to be a reasonable way to go - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-and-save-all-your-macros-in-a-single-workbook-HA102809715.aspx